# Misunderstanding semaphores process with timeout variable

Tags: c, semaphore

I'm novice with semaphores processes and I wanted to know the difference between `sem_wait` and `sem_wait_timeout`.

As I have read I think it is the same behaviour with decrement values. With timeout we can solve one of the conditions of deadlock (circuit waiting).

What is the timeout effect? I understood that the value of timeout has to be in milliseconds, but it is a random value or we have to define it?

Here it is my proposal:

```
/*Init*/
sem_init (s1, 0 , 1);
sem_init (s2, 0 , 1);

/*Thread1*/
sem_wait_timeout (s1 , int timeout);
sem_wait_timeout (s2 , int timeout);

/*Critical section*/
...

sem_signal (s2)
sem_signal (s1)
```

The thread 2 should be:

```
/*Thread2*/
sem_wait_timeout (s2 , int timeout);
sem_wait_timeout (s1 , int timeout);

/*Critical section*/
...

sem_signal (s1)
sem_signal (s2)
```

Comment: One waits forever; the other waits the specified amount of time before giving up. What else is there to say?

Comment: You might like to read here: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_wait.3.html

Comment: I did it. Pretty clear now.Best Regards